# Load function with parameters from dll

Tags: c++, dll

I load a dll in my c++ code but when run it I get error :

dll:

```
`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a,int b)
    {
       return a+b;
    }`
```

my console file:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *f_funci) (int , int);
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("ConsoleApplication1.dll");
    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    f_funci funci = 0; 
    funci = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "Add");
    if (!funci) {
        std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int t = 0;
    t= (*funci)(2, 3);
    std::cout << "funci() returned "<<t<< std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhL6E.png)

Comment: I see no __stdcall in function declaration - but you have added it to pointer definition. If you call function with wrong calling conventions you'll get error like shown in the printscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__stdcall` changes how a function is called.

Call for __stdcall on x86...

```
  push b;
  push a;
  call fnAdd;    # stack is restored by the callee. with ret 8
```

Call for __cdecl

```
  push b;
  push a;
  call fnAdd;
  add esp, 8    # restore stack.
```

This has to be matched in the function with the correct `ret` or `ret 8`.

In your case the __stdcall is causing the values a and b interfering with the registers which maintain the frame of the function.